# Using count to get number of rows from a different table as a generated column?

Tags: mysql

I have a system where a user can like content.

Both the user and content have IDs so I made a table where the user who liked the content have both their IDs stored in it.

I can get the number of users that liked the content through the SQL query.

```
SELECT count(*) from likes WHERE content_id={id of content you want the count of}
```

I thought of using generated columns but apparently that's not the way to go about it.

Currently, i just have a likes column on the content table where it is incremented every time a user likes it. However, I thought with that, there was a possibility that a bug may occur where it goes out of sync to the actual number of likes it has.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(likes_table.content_id) as likes from likes_table 
RIGHT JOIN content 
ON likes_table.content_id = content.content_id 
GROUP BY content.content_id
```

Has worked for me. If anyone has a better, more efficient solution please let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will list all columns of table `content` and will add the likes count as the last column (this is assuming that the id column in table `content` is `id`):

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT count(*) from likes WHERE content_id=id) likes
FROM content
```